# Android : Null PendingIntent

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-pendingintent

I am trying to create a PendingIntent for a broadcast receiver containing a notification and I am somehow getting a null PendingIntent returned. It makes no sense because there is only 1 case specified that would return a null PendingIntent and that is if PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE is passed as a flag option.

This is my PendingIntent code.. After in debugger pendIntent = null.

> ```
>     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LocalPushBroadcastReceiver.class);
>     notificationIntent.putExtra(LocalPushBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID_ARG, pushId);
>     notificationIntent.putExtra(LocalPushBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ARG, notification);
>     notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("LocalPush:" + pushId + notification.toString()));
>     PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
> ```

I have tried many other flag / options. I tried calling this code from onClick / onStart / everywhere. I am on the latest version of Android Studio and am compiling with the latest sdk version 25. Also LocalPushBroadcastReceiver is defined in manifest properly.

It's weird because I have this exact same code working on another machine in another application and I can't figure out what configuration I am missing. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: what is the stacktrace then?

Comment: Stacktrace is just a NPE on trying to do pendIntent.toString().

Comment: Also context is my Application class, but that didn't seem to matter as I tried context from Activity / getApplicationContext() / etc.

Comment: then debug step-by-step ~10 lines of `PendingIntent#getBroadcastAsUser(Context, int, Intent, int, UserHandle)` and you will see why it returns null

Comment: So your advice helped me a bit, I didn't think debugging that far would giev me any more info past RemoteException... 

Looks like my RemoteException I was getting was due to a Too Large Transaction Size because I am attaching a drawable converted to a bitmap as a BigPicture type to my notification parcelable. Not entirely sure how to resolve though.. Possibly converting to bitmap in a better way?

Comment: so make it smaller, or try `Notification.BigPictureStyle` - i just "discovered" this class so i have no idea what it does actually: *"Helper class for generating large-format notifications that include a large image attachment. "*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like my issue had specifically to do with the size of the notification I was attempting to pass as an argument to the PendingIntent. IMO the logging / error handling could have been a bit better here, but basically because I was attaching a large Bitmap as a BigPictureStyle to my notification, the Parcelable ended up being too large and needed to be handled differently.

tl;dr

I avoided passing the notification as a Parcelable, and instead pass an id that I use to get the proper notification when I receive my broadcast later. Thanks to pskink for the assistance debugging.

Comment: Please accept your answer. That will remove this question from the unanswered questions list. Thanks.